# LCD brightness step on T520 with Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, laptop, display, brightness

On `Lenovo T520` combination `Fn + Home/End` for increasing/decreasing screen brightness works perfectly out-of-box but with the `step = 3`. It's too coarse (HW values are `0..15`).

How to change the step to `1`?

Answer (score 1):

One way to change the brightness to individual settings is to use your console. So open a terminal (e.g. gnome-terminal) and:

1. Find where your system saves brightness settings: `sudo find /sys /proc -name brightness`. Usually they can be found in `/proc/acpi/video/*/*/brightness`, where `*` is some directory which depends on your graphics card. On my system I find the brightness settings at `/sys/devices/virtual/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`.
2. If the `find` command produces no output, check if the `video` kernel module was loaded: `lsmod | grep video` should output something like `video                  18612  0`.
3. Now check what is contained in the files the `find` command found: `cat $DIR`, where `$DIR` is the directory from `find` output. Sometimes you will only find a number and sometimes some numbers (`levels`) and the actual setting.
4. Change brightness setting: `echo $somenumber | sudo tee $DIR`, where `$somenumber` is an integer and `$DIR` the directory from the output of `find`.
5. When the command was successful executed, you will notice a changed brightness.

Answer (score 1):

on my T520i, Ubuntu 12.04, it's found in /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness, and it changes brightness but we still need the finer step on the keyboard shortcut :(

Comment: ups, seems like i cannot edit that file even with sudo?!